# How to parse a c config file that starts with { in C

Tags: c, parsing, config, configuration-files

I'm starting with reading from config files and I understood how the first example of [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Settings) and how to read values from arrays, lists, groups, etc. according to their documentation.

Now I have a config file that looks like this:

```
{    
    "value1": {
        "digit": 8,
        "digit2": 26,
        "digit3": 8
    },
    "value2": [
        { "width": 50, "height": 50, "length": 40, "wide": 50 },
{  "width": 60, "height": 80, "length": 50, "wide": 50  }
    ]
}
```

and was wondering how I read this? It's obviously a group and one of the elements has an array. However, the file starts with a `{` when I try to parse I get a

> syntax error

Does that mean I can't use the `libconfig` library to parse the file? If so which one should I use? I couldn't find any other that uses a syntax like that.

Comment: This is in json, use a json library. Libconfig is for ini-like files.

Comment: @simonzack - not according to this page: http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Configuration-Files

Comment: From looking at the libconfig docs, blocks (`{}`) are values, so they need a name. The top level block doesn't have a name.

Comment: agreed with @ColonelThirtyTwo

Comment: ok so it means I need to use a json library in order to read that ?

Comment: Looks like json to me. {} blocks are dictionaries - that means the items inside need names (which they have). The root object in the file doesn't need a name.

Comment: Also, I don't think libconfig will like quoted keys, whereas JSON requires them.